# Comments in mp3 files are seen on Mac OS but not on Windows

Tags: mp3, finder, metadata

I have a .mp3 file with some metadata, among which a comment field with a value. What's strange is that the comment can be seen on Mac OS X (both in iTunes and in the Finder), but on Windows the field appears blank. Why is this happening and is there a way to show the comment on Windows too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different formats for metadada. Usually in MP3 files the metadata are either in ID3v1, ID3v2, or APE format. There are three different versions of ID3, and [according to wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3#ID3v2), Windows can't read the latest version:

`Windows Explorer and Windows Media Player cannot handle ID3v2.4 tags in any version, up to and including Windows 8 / Windows Media Player 12.[7] Windows can understand ID3v2 up to and including version 2.3`

It could be the case that your tags are in a format that your mac can read, but windows can't.

I suggest you use a metadata editor such as [MP3tag](http://www.mp3tag.de/en/) (I use it, it's quite good, it can read/write/convert all ID3 versions, APE, read and write album images, etc). See what are the versions of ID3 present and try to convert it to a version that Windows can recognize.

Comment: It's year 2023 almost 2024 but Windows 11 still doesn't supported id3v2.4 `comment` tag. Converted to id3v2.3 everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

MacOS Finder can't read ID3v2.4.0, but it can read ID3v2.3.0. So either you mass migrate all tags using the newer version of ID3 to use the old version, or you convert everything to .mp4 what Apple wants to enforce.